# How to copy a non-trivial c++ union?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy, copy-constructor, unions

I'm trying to convert the following data structure:

```
template<typename ValueT, typename ChildT>
class MyUnion 
{
public:
    MyUnion() : mChild(NULL) {}
private:
    union {
        ChildT* mChild;
        ValueT* mValue;
    };
};
```

`ValueT` can be both POD (`int`, `float`, etc) and non-trivial stuff like `Vec3`, `std::string` which is the reason it was initially implemented as a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. However, with c++11 we can now store the value directly in the class. The result I'm looking for is this:

```
template<typename ValueT, typename ChildT>
class MyUnion 
{
public:
    MyUnion() : mChild(NULL) {}
private:
    union {
        ChildT* mChild;
        ValueT mValue;
    };
};
```

Changing this makes the compiler complain that the copy constructor is missing, so I want to implement

```
MyUnion(const MyUnion& other);
MyUnion& operator=(const MyUnion& other);
```

and ideally the move constructors also. Previously the compiler implemented these for me. With POD I could do a `memcpy` or something similar -- can I use the same now and expect correct outcome?

Comment: No, in general, you may not use `memcpy`. That's precisely what makes a class like `std::string` "non-trivial" (not trivially copyable, to be precise). You need some way to know which of the union members is currently active, and write your copy constructor accordingly. Alternatively, use something like [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: `ValueT` needs to also have a copy & move constructor / assignment / etc. It will make this a lot simpler of a task, because then you can copy-construct & move-construct it whenever `MyUnion` is. Even POD works with initialization-copy and `std::move` afaik

Comment: @XerenNarcy The problem is not so much in *how* to copy a member, as in knowing *which* member to copy.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It's both - copying a union involves identifying which element you're using as well as how to copy it. OP asked about `memcpy` and in that respect I dropped a small hint to look to the object being copied (you were more direct). That said yes - `MyUnion` needs another member to somehow track what you're doing with the union, eg `enum class` is a quick way to do it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I should add that my most important template class that I want to convert is a `Vec3` that is implemented as an array. If I go by that restriction, will `memcpy` be viable?

Comment: You could check out how this is done in e.g. `expected<T>` implementation, in any of the open source implementations floating around. See here for instance: https://github.com/martinmoene/expected-lite/blob/master/include/nonstd/expected.hpp The main thing is that, you should explicitly deinitialize and reinitialize with placement new when you want the union to be occupied by the other type. You should provide a small helper class to encapsulate that probably, at least thats what most implementations do.

Comment: If `Vec3` is trivially copyable, then implicitly-defined copy constructor should work. If it doesn't work, then `Vec3` (whatever that is) is not in fact trivially copyable, and so cannot be correctly copied with `memcpy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if `mValue` was a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, then the default copy constructor for this class was very unsafe, unless you were happy to just leak the memory.

Because, which of the copies is responsible to delete the object? They both look identical, and there is no shared pointer. So I assume that you just leaked it. (Perhaps you had some "manager" class? But then you wouldn't be asking how to store it by value in the union now, would you. So, tsk tsk for leaking :p)

In most cases what you want is to store an additional flag, which tells you which member is currently initialized. Then it is called a "discriminated union", since there is tangible info you can use to discriminate which of the two states it is in.

I'll give a minimal version that is copyable and moveable assuming that `ValueT` is.

```
template<typename ValueT, typename ChildT>
class MyUnion 
{
  public:
    // Accessors, with ref qualifiers.
    bool have_value() const { return mHaveValue; }
    ValueT & get_value() & { return mValue; }
    ValueT && get_value() && { return std::move(mValue); }
    ValueT const & get_value() const & { return mValue; }
    ChildT * & get_child() & { return mChild; }
    ChildT * && get_child() && { return mChild; }
    ChildT * const & get_child() const & { return mChild; }

    // Constructors. Default, copy, and move.

    MyUnion() {
      this->init_child(nullptr);
    }

    MyUnion(const MyUnion & other) {
      if (other.have_value()) {
        this->init_value(other.get_value());
      } else {
        this->init_child(other.get_child());
      }
    }

    MyUnion(MyUnion && other) {
      if (other.have_value()) {
        this->init_value(std::move(other.get_value()));
      } else {
        this->init_child(std::move(other.get_child()));
      }
    }

    // Move assignment operator is easier, do that first.
    // Note that if move ctors can throw, you can get a UB with this.
    // So in most correct code, you would either ban such objects from
    // appearing in your union, or try to make backup copies in order
    // to recover from the exceptions. In this code, I will just
    // assume that moving your object doesn't throw.
    // In that case, it's just deinitialize self, then use code from
    // move ctor.

    MyUnion & operator = (MyUnion && other) {
      this->deinitialize();
      if (other.have_value()) {
        this->init_value(std::move(other.get_value()));
      } else {
        this->init_child(std::move(other.get_child()));
      }
      return *this;
    }

    // Copy ctor basically uses "copy and swap", but instead of
    // swap, we use move assignment. This is exception safe, if
    // move assignment is.
    MyUnion & operator = (const MyUnion & other) {
      MyUnion temp{other};
      *this = std::move(temp);
      return *this;
    }

    // Dtor simply calls deinitialize.
    ~MyUnion() { this->deinitialize(); }

  private:
    union {
      ChildT* mChild;
      ValueT mValue;
    };
    bool mHaveValue;

    // these next three methods are private helpers for you.
    // the users of your class should not mess with these things,
    // or UB is quite likely!
    void deinitialize() {
      if (mHaveValue) {
        mValue.~ValueT();
      } else {
        // pointer type has no dtor. But if you actually *own* the child,
        // then you should call delete here I guess.
        // Or, replace with `std::unique_ptr` and call
        // that guys dtor. RAII is your friend, you can thank me later.
      }
    }

    // Initialize the value, using perfect forwarding.
    // Only do this if mValue is not currently initialized!
    template <typename ... Args>
    void init_value(Args && ... args) {
      new (&mValue) ValueT(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      mHaveValue = true;
    }

    // Here, mChild is a raw pointer, so it doesn't make sense to
    // make a similar initialization. But if you change it to be an RAII
    // object, then you should probably do a similar pattern to above,
    // with perfect forwarding.
    void init_child(ChildT * c) {
      mChild = c;
      mHaveValue = false;
    }
 };
```

Note: You don't normally need to roll your own discriminated union like this. A lot of the time, it's better to use some existing library like `boost::variant` or one of the `expected` types mentioned in comments. But, making your own little discriminated union like this is

- not that hard
- a good exercise
- sometimes a good idea if it needs to appear at an API boundary or something

In a lot of cases using a union at all is an unnecessary optimization, and you would be fine with just a `struct`. It will take more memory to represent the object, but that rarely matters and it might be easier to understand / easier for your team to maintain.

Comment: I only showed the principle parts of the code that I wanted to change -- there were no memory leak before so no worries :) My implementation turned out similar to what you've provided, but I might steal a few tricks from you! However, it feels like you missed the most important part: the goal was to not need heap allocated memory with `new`. Other than that I fully agree with your solution.

Comment: Well, my code doesn't use new anywhere. If you don't want `ChildT` to be a pointer then make it a value-type like `ValueT` in my example.

Comment: Oh, I be confused how stuff works. What does `new (&mValue) ValueT(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` do?

Comment: That is placement new. It constructs a new `ValueT` exactly at the location `mValue`. https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't `memcpy` something which which is not trivially copyable - and `std::string` certainly is not.

Moreover, to access the non-trivial member of this union you have to first call a placement new operator on it - otherwise, it's constructor won't be called, and it will remain uninitialized.

I basically find the usage of non-trivial types in unions usually a dubious practice, but not everybody agrees with me.